# How to apply css style for HTML element using Mootools

Tags: css, mootools

How can we hide all list element from first form in following html structure using mootools

```
<form method="post" action="/signup" class="global_form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<div>
    <div>
        <ul class="form-errors">    
            <li>First Name
                <ul class="errors">
                    <li>Please provide a valid answer for this field.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Last name
                <ul class="errors">
                    <li>Please provide a valid answer for this field.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</form>


 <form method="post" id="user_form_login" action="/login" class="global_form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<div>
    <div>
        <ul class="form-errors">    
            <li>Uername
                <ul class="errors">
                    <li>Please provide a valid answer for this field.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Password
                <ul class="errors">
                    <li>Please provide a valid answer for this field.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely untested and I switched to jQuery a while ago so there might be a cleaner way to do this, but this should give you a basic idea.

If you are trying to select multiple elements use the mootools [dollars](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars) method.

If you were to append an `id` to the first form you could do something like this...

`$$('#form1 li').setStyle('display', 'none');`

### OR

If you do not want to add an `id` tag this might work.

```
var firstForm = $$("form").getFirst(),
listElements = firstForm.getChildren('li');

listelements.setStyle('display', 'none');
```